# Trying to 'Make' CUDA SDK, ld cannot find library, ldconfig says it can

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, cuda, linker-errors

*I know there are many other questions similar to this one, but none of the solutions posited there are working for me*

Basically, making the SDK sample files, i get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda`
 which would be an easy enough 'find the library and throw it to ldconfig', except ldconfig already says it has it...

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep cuda
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
    libcudartemu.so.3 -> libcudartemu.so.3.0.14
    libcudart.so.3 -> libcudart.so.3.0.14
/usr/local/cuda/lib:
    libcudartemu.so.3 -> libcudartemu.so.3.0.14
    libcudart.so.3 -> libcudart.so.3.0.14
    libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.195.36.15
    libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.195.36.15
    libicudata.so.42 -> libicudata.so.42.1
```

And I checked, there is a symlink `libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.1` but I'm still confused as to why `libcuda.so -> ...` doesnt show up

I must be missing something really obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Found this question via Google.  Since I'm now having a similar problem 3 years later, I thought I'd note my solution: For at least the CUDA 5.0 SDK samples and my current driver (304.64), this issue can be solved by using `make EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L /usr/lib64/nvidia"` (switch lib64 for lib on 32-bit systems). The linker is looking in /usr/lib(64) but the driver installed things in usr/lib(64)/nvidia, but the provided makefiles make use of `EXTRA_LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ldconfig` deals only with runtime libraries, whereas `ld` deals with build-time libraries. Depending on how you installed the CUDA libraries, you may need to install an additional package for the symlink used at buildtime, or you may need to pass a `-L` option to gcc or ld in order to tell it where the build-time symlink is.

Comment: IANA experienced coder, so I understood roughly 70% of what you just said :D but is there somewhere to add these paths to instead of _Ling them all the time, similar to the $PATH envvar? 
I've already tried adding the directories to a conf file under ld.so.conf.d, but that fixed nothing.

Comment: No. And modifying `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` only affects ld.so, which only affects runtime. If you want some sort of semi-permanent solution then you should look into creating a makefile for your project.

Comment: This is actually a shortcoming in the CUDA SDK Makefiles. They should pass the current -L option by default. The current place to put it is `C/common/common.mk:148`. Change this line to `LINKFLAGS += -L/usr/lib/nvidia-current`.

Answer (score 8):

Add to .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
export LPATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and source .bash_profile

Comment: As a temporary fix you can also do `make LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LIBRARY_PATH` when building the SDK code samples.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but soon I found this doesn't work for me and I can't undo the upvote. However, I'm using another library instead of CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -L/usr/local/cuda/lib before -lcuda on the compiler/linker command line.

Comment: FYI, Because of the grepping, libcuda isnt actually in /usr/local/cuda/lib, its in /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda